# Bad Request as Response

Tags: android, facebook

I tried to get the `facebook` wall data.I got my access token by using

```
accesstoken=Login.mFacebook.getAccessToken();
Log.e("accesstoken",accesstoken);
```

But while calling

```
String wallres=UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?     access_token=accesstoken");
Log.e("wall res",wallres);
```

I am getting Bad Request as response

Comment: Was my answer an answer to your question? If so, please accept/upvote it. It is the least you can do when somebody invests time in helping you.

Answer (score 0):

By calling this code you say that accesstoken is literally part of the URL.

```
String wallres=UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?     access_token=accesstoken");
```

I think you meant to do this, so that you use the previously defined variable `accesstoken`:

```
String wallres=UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?     access_token=" + accesstoken);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already a problem like this. Try remove the spaces or convert it to %20.

```
String wallres=UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=accesstoken");
Log.e("wall res",wallres);
```

Regards, Hugo Pedrosa